# R leaflet provider tiles basemaps - pass API codes tokens of HERE

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, here-api

I am using the R leaflet package (using R Shiny) and I would like to add a HERE basemap through the function "addProviderTiles". How do I pass the App_Id and App_Code of a HERE provider basemap to leaflet in R?

Example code:

```
m_rent<-leaflet::leaflet() 
m_rent<-setView(m_rent,lng=9.0,lat=47.0,zoom=12) 
#### how do I pass the API credentials?
m_rent<-addProviderTiles(m_rent,"HERE.hybridDay",...............) 
m_rent
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: m_rent<-leaflet::leaflet()
m_rent<-setView(m_rent,lng=9.0,lat=47.0,zoom=12)
m_rent<-addProviderTiles(m_rent,"HERE.hybridDay",...............) #### how do I pass the API credentials?

m_rent

Answer (score 3):

You should use the addTiles function instead of addProviderTiles
It worked for me this way:

```
m_rent<-leaflet::leaflet() 
m_rent<-setView(m_rent,lng=9.0,lat=47.0,zoom=12)
html <- "http://1.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/hybrid.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png?app_id={your_app_id}&app_code={your_app_code}&lg=eng"
m_rent<-addTiles(m_rent,html)
m_rent
```

For more information you should check:

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/quick-start.html
   http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=HERE.hybridDay

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer to my question. The credentials are passed as follows:

```
m_rent <- addProviderTiles(m_rent,"HERE.hybridDay",options=providerTileOptions(app_id="...",app_code="..."))
```